# How to use existing maven project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am new to java and eclipse environment. I have an existing maven project which i need to edit using eclipse IDE. I have not maven or m2eclipse plugin installed on my machine. Please can anyone tell me how to install maven and spring framework on my machine and link it to eclipse so that I can open existing maven project in eclipse. I would be grateful if anyone tells me If any Step by step tutorial is there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a maven plugin in eclipse. m2e is one of such plugins, which can be downloaded from http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/ Once downloaded, you can import the maven project by following File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects. Provide the location of your project directory (where pom.xml is located) and eclipse should be able to get it setup in your workspace.

EDIT: you may have to restart eclipse once the plugin is installed.

Comment: there is a step by step guide (with screenshots) as well for doing this: http://www.onehippo.org/7_7/library/development/import-a-project-into-eclipse.html

Comment: Thanks Pat for your quick response. You saves my lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Install the jboss tools package in eclipse. Help->Eclipse Marketplace...  Search for "Jboss Tools" and install the one that matches your version of eclipse.  This will allow you to import an existing maven project after you restart eclipse. File -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project

Comment: Thanks kharyam for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.0/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-win32.zip

Download this Eclipse Spring Tool. You can use every spring project with it.